# How to link the rank of Elliptic Surfaces and Elliptic Curves over function fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry, rational-functions, elliptic-surfaces

I have been investigating certain elliptic surfaces for my research, and when giving a presentation, I was asked why when given an elliptic surface $E$, say given in Weierstrass form
$$E\colon y^2+a_1(T)xy+a_3(T)y=x^3+a_2(T)x^2+a_4(T)x+a_6(T)$$
you obtain a rank $\mathrm{Rank}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ that is necessarily the same as $\mathrm{Rank}(E/\mathbb{Q}(T))$, considering the elliptic surface as an elliptic curve over the rational function field $\mathbb{Q}(T)$. I will be giving another talk soon, but I have not been able to find a satisfactory explanation as to why the rank of the elliptic surface matches the rank obtained by the group law on the corresponding elliptic curve. Any support is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose the elliptic surface E --> P_1(Q) is non-split.  Then Silverman's specialization theorem implies that for all but finitely many specialization t\in Q, the rank of the elliptic curves is <= the rank of the specialization E_t(Q); see Advanced Topics in Arith of EC, thm III.11.4 for the precise statement.  Now, rank can jump *up* in specialization, but it is relatively rare, and often (but not always!) one can quantify the amount of "jump" in rank upon specialization.

Comment: I think by $\mathrm{Rank}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ he means the rank of the Neron-Severi group of the surface $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If so, it is not quite correct. See for example the Corollary, p.182, of Gordon, W. J. Linking the conjectures of Artin-Tate and Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer. Compositio Math. 38 (1979), no. 2, 163--199.

Comment: What are you saying has smaller rank? Is rank(E/Q)<=rank(E/Q(T)) or the other way round? I am using E/Q as the elliptic surface, and E/Q(T) as the elliptic curve over Q(T).

Comment: As in the paper I cited, the rank of the Neron-Severi group of the elliptic surface equals  2+the rank of the Mordell-Weil group of the elliptic curve +a sum of local terms coming from the reducible fibers.